# Default country and state selection in HTML and PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a form with selecting country and state. While accessing the form default country should set as India and default state should be Karnataka. Below is my code. How can I achieve this.

```
<?php
//country sql
$con_sql ="SELECT a.`id_country`, b.`name` AS `name`, `iso_code`, `call_prefix`, z.`id_zone` AS `zone`, a.`active` AS `active` , z.`name` AS zone      FROM `country` a LEFT JOIN `country_lang` b ON (b.`id_country` = a.`id_country` AND b.`id_lang` = 1) LEFT JOIN `zone` z ON (z.`id_zone` = a.`id_zone`) WHERE 1  ORDER BY b.`name` ASC";
$con_res = mysqli_query($con, $con_sql);
if($con_res !== null){
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($con_res))
  {
    echo '<option   value="'.$row['id_country'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
  }
 } else { echo '<option value="">country is not available</option>';            }?>
</select>
<input style="margin-top:-3%; margin-left:46.5%" type="text" name="code" id="code" value="" >

</div></br>

<div class="">
    <span1 style="color:red;">*</span1>  <span>State</span><br>
  <!--  <span style="margin-left:40%">Members</span><br> -->

    <select  name="state" id="state" class="state" required/>
        <option value="" disabled selected>--select--</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default option can be enforced by an `selected` HTML attribute within the  tag

You could use an if condition to use this attribute when required.
eg.

```
$defaultCountry = 'India';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($con_res)) { 
    $isDefaultCountry = $row['name'] === $defaultCountry; // boolean (true/false)

    echo '<option '. (($isDefaultCountry ? 'selected' : '')).' value="'.htmlentities($row['id_country']).'">'.htmlentities($row['name']).'</option>';
}
```

Sidenote: Make sure to encode your values that are rendered into HTML.
eg.

`echo '<option   value="'.$row['id_country'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';`

should become

`echo '<option value="'.htmlentities($row['id_country']).'">'.htmlentities($row['name']).'</option>';`

Otherwise you could end up allowing your page to be compromised

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: at the same time state should be "Karnataka" but its not coming as of now